# I downloaded JDeveloper version 12. Using Java. I cannot find the window to accept user input from the Scanner class Where is the tool settings win?

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I downloaded JDeveloper version 12. Using Java.
I cannot find the window to accept user input.
I am using the Scanner class.
When I run the program, the debugger does not allow user input.
I tried using the Application properties, could not find tool settings to check box allow user input. Any suggestions? My first question!

Answer (score 0):

I found the  answer.  Here it is:
Right click on project node and select project properties.
Select Run/Debug/Profile and edit the "Default" run configuration.
Select "Tool Settings" and enable "Allow Program Input"